# On listening from Azure Event Hub I am getting error

Tags: azure-eventhub

On listening from Azure Event Hub I am getting error

> The supplied offset XXXXX is invalid. The last offset in the system is  XXXXX
>
> Error on Partition 1: The AMQP Object session is aborted.
> Error on Partition 0: The supplied offset is invalid.

Comment: Are you providing an offset? If so you have the wrong one. Is [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/issues/13) helpful?

Comment: No I am not providing any offset.

Comment: I am inheriting from IEventProcessor so I am not providing any offset.

Comment: And you are not passing any parameters to / setting any properties of the `EventProcessorHost`? Can you post the code where you do the initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was because of sharing an instance of EventPosition class.

```cs
var position = EventPosition.FromStart();

var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(
    eventHubName,
    consumerGroupName,
    eventHubConnectionString,
    storageConnectionString,
    LeaseContainerName);

host.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(
    processorFactory,
    new EventProcessorOptions
    {
        // Problem is the following line.
        // In order to fix it replace 'position' with 'EventPosition.FromStart()'
        InitialOffsetProvider = partitionId => position  
    }).Wait();
```

Apparently, if you share an instance of position class, then ProcessorHost uses the same object for different IEventProcessor(s). As this object contains offset value it leads to passing the same offset to different partitions - obviously, it leads to the problem if an offset is different among partitions.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is likely to be happening due to the fact that the index that the eventhub consumer/listener was keeping got out of sync with the index that the eventhub can provide.

In my case the eventhub was re-created, so its own index returned to -1, or empty, while the azure function connecting to it was expecting for something above e.g. 1000. This was an obvious error from the eventhub standpoint because it has never reach such index by its own.

#### Solution

Reset the index that the azure function is keeping to connect to this eventhub.

**When running in the cloud** is solved [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-set-offset-for-event-hubs-trigger/ba-p/3871873) on the *Check the offset* section.

##### When running a local `func start`

This was my case. For an local dev env like this to work you need a web storage to connect to. This is easily done by having in `local.settings.json`:

```json
{
  "Values": {
    ...
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

and running the azurite docker image like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=docker-hub):

```bash
$ docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
```

If this happens with this setup you should go into the docker container using a terminal and run:

```bash
# rm -r /data/*
```

this will clear all indexes and previous records. Will solve the problem for sure. *But use it carefully* if you are interested in keeping records for other subscriptions.